# DateTime.Now to mysql datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

i got problem with a query, got something like this

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT " +
        "COUNT(a.`id`) " +
   "FROM " +
        "`messageaccess` a " +
   "WHERE " +
        "a.`Users_LOGIN` = '" + Settings.UserLogin + "' " +
        "AND a.`Status` = '" + Enums.MessageStatus.New + "' " +
        "AND a.`FOLDER` = '" + Enums.MessageFolder.INBOX + "'" +
        "AND a.`ShowAlert` = '" + Enums.YesNo.No + "'" +
        "AND a.`Postponed` <= " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "";
```

but sql throws me exception 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:40:37' at line 1

tried diffrent combinantions but nothing works :(

Comment: Your code has several [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection+vulnerability). Please find out what this term means and fix your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the quotation marks around the date/time thing.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is not to embed values directly into the SQL to start with.

Use a parameterized SQL statement, specify the parameter value as `DateTime.Now`, and all will be well:

- Your SQL will be easier to read (as it'll *just* be the code, not the data)
- You won't need to worry about formatting of things like numbers and dates
- You won't be vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I honestly don’t think the xkcd link is very helpful to novices who don’t already understand SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

try using this line instead:

```
"AND a.`Postponed` <= NOW()"
```

and it should work with the native MySql function for the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at named [parameterized queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters). They take care of these formatting issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't build your query appending strings. This is not very safe (sql injection) and you're not taking advantage of the ADO .NET capabilities to set the correct format according the parameter type.

You should use parametrized queries.